# Confusing function type usage in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-function-type

I'm reading the kotlin coroutine source code.

see the code snaps below:

```
  public operator fun <R, T> invoke(block: suspend R.() -> T, receiver: R, completion: Continuation<T>): Unit =
        when (this) {
            DEFAULT -> block.startCoroutineCancellable(receiver, completion)
            ATOMIC -> block.startCoroutine(receiver, completion)
            UNDISPATCHED -> block.startCoroutineUndispatched(receiver, completion)
            LAZY -> Unit // will start lazily
        }
```

in CoroutineStart.kt

and

```
  internal fun <R, T> (suspend (R) -> T).startCoroutineCancellable(
    receiver: R, completion: Continuation<T>,
    onCancellation: ((cause: Throwable) -> Unit)? = null
) =
    runSafely(completion) {
        createCoroutineUnintercepted(receiver, completion).intercepted().resumeCancellableWith(Result.success(Unit), onCancellation)
    }
```

In Cancellable.kt

What my confusion is:

`block` as a function which type is `R.() -> T`,
how can it invoke  `startCoroutineCancellable` which function type of `(R) -> T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the "[Function Types](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#function-types)" section of the language spec (emphasis mine).

> A function type with receive `FTR`
>
> ```
> FTR(RT, A1, A2, ... An) -> R
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> From the type system’s point of view, it is equivalent to the
> following function type
>
> ```
> FTR(RT, A1, A2, ... An) -> R ≡ FT(RT, A1, A2, ... An) -> R
> ```
>
> ***i.e. receiver is considered as yet another argument of its function type.***
>
> [...] for example, these two types are equivalent w.r.t. type system
>
> ```
> Int.(Int) -> String
> (Int, Int) -> String
> ```

So an instance of `R.() -> T` can totally be used as the receiver of an extension on `(R) -> T` and vice versa, because the type system sees them as the same thing.

Do note that these two types are not the same in the context of overload resolution. For example, if you say `someInt.bar()`, and there are two `bar`s in scope, one with type `Int.() -> Unit` and the other with type `(Int) -> Unit`, then overload resolution will know that these are functions with different types and pick the former one.

Side note: the function types used in `startCoroutineCancellable` and `invoke` are technically [suspending function types](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/type-system.html#suspending-function-types), but what is said above still applies.

Answer (score 2):

`R.() -> T` and `(R) -> T` are very similar function types from the caller perspective. They just receive `R` and return `T`. They differ mostly from the perspective of their body. See this example:

```kotlin
val f1: Int.() -> String = { toString() }
val f2: (Int) -> String = f1
val f3: Int.() -> String = f2
```

As we can see, we can convert between both types freely, even without an explicit cast.

Answer (score 2):

A concise and simple way to put it is that a function type defined with a receiver has the same signature as one where that receiver is moved into the parameters as the first parameter. They are interchangeable just about everywhere except when using lambdas to represent them, and when calling invoke on them. You can call a function with receiver with the receiver transposed to first parameter (but not vice versa, calling a receiverless function on an instance of its first parameter).

Comment: Thx, I really appreciate your help.:)