# Receiver used as first parameter for extension function calling?

Tags: kotlin, builder

I am studying kotlin builder syntax, on js platform, and got some code running but cannot understand, pls help.
`building` function as a parameter here, has a receiver. But when I call it, i pass no receiver to it. Is first parameter used as receiver here?

```kotlin
import react.dom.svg.SVGAttributes
import kotlin.js.Json

fun test(){
    val svg = svgB{
        width = 100.0
        //.....
        height = 40.0
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(svg))
    //{"width":100,"height":40,......}
}


fun svgB(building: SVGAttributes<*>.() -> Unit): Json {
    val obj: dynamic = js("{}")
    building(obj) // why this works?
    //obj.building() // this is not working, which I understood. Because {} have no building method.
    return obj
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because the type `T.() -> Unit` is the same as `(T) -> Unit` from the type system's perspective, just with some extra overload resolution rules, allowing you to call it by using a `T` in the receiver position. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71140102/confusing-function-type-usage-in-kotlin/71140526#71140526).

Since you can call `(T) -> Unit` by passing the parameter in `(...)`, you can do that with `T.() -> Unit` too.

The more interesting thing here is that `obj.building()` doesn't work. This is because `obj` is of the type `dynamic`. It would have worked if `obj` were a `SVGAttributes<*>`, not `dynamic`, since `building` is declared to have `SVGAttributes<*>` as its receiver.

Overload resolution is [specifically designed](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/dynamic-types.md#resolution-rules) to not look for non-`dynamic` extensions if the receiver is `dynamic`.

> NOTE: we do not even try to resolve extensions declared for static types if the receiver is dynamic. As a workaround, one may use an upcast to a static type: `(dyn as Foo).extensionForFoo()`.
>
> Motivation: otherwise, any extension to any type that simply happens to be in scope and match the name and arguments will be bound for a call with a dynamic receiver, i.e. there's no way to force a call to be dynamic, and in the case of a *-import the code may change its semantics just because somebody added some extension in another file.

As the quote said, you can use `(obj as SVGAttributes<*>).building()` instead, if you want `obj` to be in the receiver position.